# How do i know if processor has xmm registers or ymm ones

Tags: c++

guys, imagine I have a template function:

```
template <typename T> Vector<T>* Vector<T>::overwrite(const Vector<T>* copy) {
    this->_normalized = copy->_normalized;

    this->_data[0] = copy->_data[0];
    this->_data[1] = copy->_data[1];
    this->_data[2] = copy->_data[2];
    this->_data[3] = copy->_data[3];

    return this;
}
```

and a specification for it:

```
template <> Vector<float>* Vector<float>::overwrite(const Vector<float>* copy) {
    __m128 data = _mm_load_ps(copy->_data);

    _mm_store_ps(this->_data, data);

    return this;
}
```

Now I'd like to make sure SSE is supported by the processor, particularly that processor has XMM registers to copy 4 floats using 1 instruction. Then I would like to have same function for **double** so I would need YMM registers.

So I want to know if there is a way to determine XMM and YMM availability during run-time.

Another more preferrable option is to somehow know that during preprocessor work out. I.e. so that I write something like:

```
template <typename T> Vector<T>* Vector<T>::overwrite(const Vector<T>* copy) {
    this->_normalized = copy->_normalized;

    this->_data[0] = copy->_data[0];
    this->_data[1] = copy->_data[1];
    this->_data[2] = copy->_data[2];
    this->_data[3] = copy->_data[3];

    return this;
}

#ifdef XMM_ARE_AVAILABLE
template <> Vector<float>* Vector<float>::overwrite(const Vector<float>* copy) {
    __m128 data = _mm_load_ps(copy->_data);

    _mm_store_ps(this->_data, data);

    return this;
}
#endif

#ifdef YMM_ARE_AVAILABLE
template <> Vector<double>* Vector<double>::overwrite(const Vector<double>* copy) {
    /* code that moves four doubles */

    return this;
}
#endif
```

Thanks!

Comment: I wouldn't do that check at run-time, you risk **overhead** for the check (or pointer indirection if you keep a function pointers table) will vanish (all of part) performance you gain using SSE/MMX instructions. IMO it's much better to provide two (or more) **different versions of your library** (made with conditional compilation) picking the right one during **installation**.

Comment: If a single indirect dispatch loses you the advantage of your SIMD routine, then your SIMD routine isn't good enough.

Comment: @SebastianRedl I would use them even to perform **few simple calculations** (imagine, for example, to calculate distance of two points with two different inputs). In this case **gain is pretty small** but you may need it (otherwise you'd better to **do not program with SIMD** at all and to leave compiler do its work). In this case you may lose 10/20% (or more) performance gain. **No reason to put such effort if you don't care of performance.**

Comment: You can use the CPUID instruction to detect feature support.  http://www.sandpile.org/x86/cpuid.htm  One way to handle different support is to make an implementation for each and instantiate the one that best matches the processor you're running on at runtime.  You still have some indirection, but you only need to check once.

Comment: @RetiredNinja not really. You need to check one but you still need to call that functions through a pointer. This will be a penalty in performance because of pointer itself and because it'll **stop compiler to do other optimizations** (inlining but also registry optimizations across functions and many many more). Sure this make your function much slower than the version without SIMD...

Comment: Thanks guys I like your replies. I'm pretty new to that stuff.

Different versions of the library with conditional compilation is a good option but won't work for me. http://www.sandpile.org/x86/cpuid.htm is a cool link, I didn't see it  while googling cpuid. So far sounds like cpuid and function pointers is rather graceful solution but I'm afraid of performance gain being lost as stated by Adriano. Let's see what it will eventually come to.

Comment: @Adriano If you have to check at runtime you have to accept that there will be an indirection or branch to choose the right implementation to use.  It depends on the actual operations done whether this penalty overshadows any performance gain you obtain from using the SIMD instructions.  As you said above, it is better to target the correct instruction set at compile time, but you can't always do that, and there can be benefit from runtime checking.  That's what profiling is for, to decide if it's worth it.

Comment: @RetiredNinja **no**, many times you do not need to check at run-time at all because you do it once during installation. Please do not forget that we're talking about OPTIMIZATIONS. **If you take the effort to do it then you wouldn't waste half of what you gain.**. That said **profiling** should be done in **advance to decide if SIMD is needed or not.**. It's not a check to see if an API function is available or not...it's something he's doing to boost performance, no room for wastage.

Comment: @Adriano  I get it, this is a hot button issue for you, so this will be my last comment.  That said, *if* you need to do this at runtime then there is a way to do it.  Is it better to avoid having to do it that way if you can?  Yes.  Is it possible to get huge gains by handling it at runtime?  Also, yes.  It just depends on the circumstances.

Comment: @RetiredNinja I'm not native speaker so I'm sorry if I did look too "involved" in the question. I agree that function pointers are a possible way (as I mentioned in my very first comment), I just wanted to strongly warn him about their overhead (both direct and _indirect_) when used in an optimized function. That said, as for everything, it depends on the circumstances!

Comment: @Adriano Optimization is not a black/white thing. You optimize something to make it *fast enough* for your needs. You do not optimize it to be as fast as at all possible under any circumstances whatsoever. If you have this runtime check, your code will be slower than if you didn't have it, but it can still be much faster than if it didn't use SIMD at all. And often, that is *good enough*

Comment: @jalf in general I may agree, I was concerned about this case because function itself is really small. CPUs available today are better than what was available when question has been asked. What I mean? If he is trying to fine tune such small block of code then to accept a performance penality for a tuntime check can be pretty strange. It's not a function that will perform 1M floating point operations (where such overhead is really little).

Comment: Of course it should be measured, if he had to reduce a task (for example) from 50 us to 40 us (so to do not get best performance but _good enough_ for his scenario) then a runtime check can do it. In general (and without more info) I can't imagine this is such critical routine and (especially) I can't imagine it's the only one he has to tune. Of course...IMO.

Answer (score 0):

It is far better to convince the compiler to vectorize this itself than writing specialized code with intrinsics or asm.  The troublesome part is the pointers (or references, if they had been used), both the Vector argument pointer and "this."

Unfortunately C++ doesn't support "restrict" directly but most compilers should have some kind of implementation-specific attribute to do it.  Use `__restrict__` with g++, which also works on function types to restirct "this":

http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Restricted-Pointers.html

Some compilers (llvm, for example), can vectorize loops unrolled into straight-line code as in your example.  Others will want to have the loop re-rolled.  Generally for auto-vectorization purposes it's better to write loops than hand-unrolled code.

This example is a trivial case for auto-vectorization and you'll have more portable code.

Comment: How does this address the problem of knowing whether the CPU it is running on supports SIMD instructions?

Comment: It's an alternative implementation.  It seems as though the real goal here is to use SIMD instructions to copy Vectors.  The compiler already knows whether the target supports them.

Comment: Yes, the compiler knows which instruction set it targets. It does not know which CPU you're running the code on. If you tell the compiler to target a CPU with, say, SSE2 support, then you can still, at runtime, detect if AVX is supported, and call into AVX-optimized code. The OP is asking how to detect this at runtime. And your question doesn't answer it. :)

Comment: jalf, compilers can emit multiple versions of the code for multiple targets just fine.  The PGI compiler, for example, does this.  gcc does not, as far as I'm aware.

Comment: But your answer does not answer the question: he wants the code to dynamically use SSE if it is available, and avoid it if it is not available. Your answer just says "let the compiler autogenerate SSE code". That has nothing to do with his question. Unless you amend a note that "this will solve your problem iff. you have a compiler that can silently generate both execution paths plus code to dynamically switch between them"